# SwiftUI Context Menu with image like Photos app

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu

I would like to use the context menu in the same way as the Apple photo application does: when you press a square image for a long time, you get a full screen preview of the image in the original format of the image and not square like in the grid. But when I use the context menu, the preview is in the same format as the one displayed.

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
struct CardView: View {
    let url: URL
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            AnimatedImage(url: url)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(4)
                .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Button {
                        print("Saved \(url)")
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Save Image")
                                .padding(20)
                            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.down")
                                .resizable()
                                .font(.title)
                        }
                    }
                }))
        }
    }
}
```